# Excel conditional formatting rules propigate endlessly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a series of Excel workbooks edited daily by users. At their request I added conditional formatting rules to call out important data. Below is an example of the basic set I add for everyone.

[image: Hundreds of rows deep]

A consistent problem we are having is the rules seem to multiply over time. As the users manipulate the data they generate more and more rules without ever touching the Conditional Formatting tool. The user below easily has hundreds if not thousands.

[image: Nice and Neat]
Is there a way to set the rules then lock them somehow?

Comment: Is protecting the worksheet an option?

Answer (score 2):

It would be really nice if Excel had a user mode vs. developer mode, but it doesn't.  It always works in "developer mode", by which I mean that a simple cut & paste moves everything (like formatting), even when user's aren't expecting that.

I think you'd have to use VBA to set (and reset/clear) the background color; you'd have to hook into something like the `Sub Worksheet_Calculate ()` event to run your vb whenever Excel recacluates.